# Meaning of Error: Cannot redeclare bootstrap_preprocess_region()

Tags: theming

I'm setting up a Drupal Bootstrap subtheme, and ran into this fatal error when trying to clear my cache. Something seemed to want to redeclare a bootstrap preprocess function:

> Error: Cannot redeclare bootstrap_preprocess_region()

This caused the whole site to go down and Drush to fail any time I tried to clear or rebuild the cache.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I'd copied `.func.php` files from the templates folder of the Bootstrap parent theme into my base theme alongside `.tpl.php` files. Bootstrap is relatively unusual in that it has files in the templates folder alongside `tpl` files that will break the site if they're treated like standard theme `tpl` files.

While the `.tpl.php` files are to be copied as normal, to override the contents of the other files, you are expected to copy their appropriate *contents* into your subtheme's `template.php` file or into a new `.func.php` file, and substitute your subtheme name for the `bootstrap` part of the function name.

There's some more information on the [theme registry](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21registry%21README.md/group/registry/7) docs page.